# Maven plugins via profile are not executed in specified phase

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

My requirement to execute testng.xml file to run the automation scripts and send the mail once execution is completed. I'll define like what tests to run from testng.xml file.

So I've decided to use maven profiles concept for running the testng.xml file and for sending execution reports as below. When i run the command using 
"mvn test -P Code_Compile,Run_Tests,Mail_Reports", below mentioned profiles are not executed. Please let me know what I'm missing here.

```
<profiles>  
    <profile>
        <id>Code_Compile</id>
            <build>
                  <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7.0</version>                        
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>codecompile</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                  <source>1.8</source>
                                  <target>1.8</target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>                       
                  </plugin>                           
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>


    <profile>
    <id>Run_Tests</id>
        <build>
              <plugins>                   
                  <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>runtests</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                                  <suiteXmlFiles>
                                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                                  </suiteXmlFiles>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>                         
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>Mail_Reports</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.1.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>send a mail</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>send-mail</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <inherited>false</inherited>
                            <configuration>
                                <from>xx@gmail.com</from>
                                <subject>Latest Automation Report...</subject>
                                <failonerror>true</failonerror>
                                <mailhost>smtp.gmail.com</mailhost>
                                <mailport>465</mailport>
                                <mailssl>true</mailssl>
                                <mailAltConfig>true</mailAltConfig>
                                <mailuser>xx@gmail.com</mailuser>
                                <mailpassword>xxxxx</mailpassword>
                                <htmlMessage><![CDATA[<p>Hi, Please find enclosed latest Automation reports.</p>]]></htmlMessage>
                                <receivers>
                                    <receiver>xxxx@gmail.com</receiver>
                                </receivers>
                                <fileSets>
                                    <fileSet>
                                        <directory>${basedir}/TestReports</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>LatestAutomationReport.zip</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileSet>
                                </fileSets>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    </profiles>
```

I've tried to include only plugins inside build tag instead of profiles by setting the phase as "test" for each plugin as shown below and tried to run "mvn test" command.As you can see below I've included test in each plugin.This try also didn't pick the execution of plugins. Please help me in solving this problem either via profiles or via plugins.

```
<build>
<plugins>  
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>                        
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>codecompile</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <source>1.8</source>
                      <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>                       
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>runtests</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                      <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                      </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>send a mail</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>send-mail</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <from>vikascool4@gmail.com</from>
                        <subject>Latest Automation Report...</subject>
                        <failonerror>true</failonerror>
                        <mailhost>smtp.gmail.com</mailhost>
                        <mailport>465</mailport>
                        <mailssl>true</mailssl>
                        <mailAltConfig>true</mailAltConfig>
                        <mailuser>vikascool4@gmail.com</mailuser>
                        <mailpassword>vikaschinna</mailpassword>
                        <htmlMessage><![CDATA[<p>Hi, Please find enclosed latest Automation reports.</p>]]></htmlMessage>
                        <receivers>
                            <receiver>vikas.voladri@gmail.com</receiver>
                        </receivers>
                        <fileSets>
                            <fileSet>
                                <directory>${basedir}/TestReports</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>LatestAutomationReport.zip</include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileSet>
                        </fileSets>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>  
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run `mvn fr.jcgay.maven.plugins:buildplan-maven-plugin:1.3:list -P Code_Compile,Run_Tests,Mail_Reports`this will output the plugins maven is executing and their execution ids, You might see from the output of the command that your executions are probably not overriding the default executions (as these have different ids).

Instead of defining your `Code_Compile` profile use the default properties defined here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Also if you want to use a specific version of the compiler use `pluginManagement` to define that.

Comment: I've removed comiple related profile and included in properties tag. I've ran above command as mvn fr.jcgay.maven.plugins:buildplan-maven-plugin:1.3:list -P Run_Tests,Mail_Reports and in the output i could see 'runtests', 'send a mail' under ID column.